# Issues loading `InfixNotation` as part of a package

Tags: packages, custom-notation

For the most part, elements of the [`Notation` package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) that are part of a package I load work without issues, but [`InfixNotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/InfixNotation.html) appears not to be correctly parsed by package load

For example if I have a package containing

```
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[CircleTimes]"],KroneckerProduct];
```

this has no effect when loaded. Is there something additional I need to do to load `InfixNotation` definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to put `InfixNotation` before the "Private" section of your package:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

BeginPackage["NBug`",{"Notation`"}];

Unprotect@@Names["NBug`*"];
ClearAll@@Names["NBug`*"];

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[CircleTimes]"],TensorProduct] ;
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[CenterDot]"],Dot] ;

Begin["`Private`"];
(* Don't put InfixNotation here *)

End[];(*`Private`*)

EndPackage[];
```